# Razor. How to use partial view with IQueryable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm completely new to Razor engine, so may be my question look silly. Anyway. I need to use partial view in main view and I'm passing my model that inherited IQueryable interface.
This look like that:

```
 @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/comments/Details.cshtml", new IQueryable<BlogAspNetMVC.Models.comments>);}
```

Partial view model:

```
@model IQueryable<BlogAspNetMVC.Models.comments>
```

How should I change RenderPartial to be able accept this model as argument?

P.S.
Here is comments model:

```
  public partial class comments
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Author { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Posted { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> PostID { get; set; }

        public virtual blog_post blog_post { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is Icomments interface:

```
public interface IComments : IDisposable
{
    IQueryable<comments> GetPostComments(int postid);
    //void Add(comments comment);
    //void Update(comments comment);
    //void Remove(int id);
}
```

This how implemented in repository:

```
public IQueryable<comments> GetPostComments(int postid)
        {
            var all = from a in db.comments
                      orderby a.Posted descending
                      where a.PostID == postid
                      select a;
            return all.AsQueryable();
        }
```

Comment: What is the type of `BlogAspNetMVC.Models.comments`?

Comment: I should also add that it is unusual to have an `IQueryable` of an item that is already a plural. It's akin to having a set of sets, which in this context might not make sense.

Comment: It seemed like without IQueryable I can't use foreach statement as it's not support GetEnumerator().

Comment: What is your model for the view that has the call to RenderPartial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what you've posted this should pass the correct type:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/comments/Details.cshtml", 
                  new List<BlogAspNetMVC.Models.comments>().AsQueryable());
```

Although, you're just passing an empty collection. I suspect you are missing some data from the model from your parent view that you should really be passing to RenderPartial.

Comment: Does not contain definition of AsQueryable()

Comment: Then `comments` is not an `IEnumerable`. I suspect you really don't want `IQueryable` in your view.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i tried and it worked for me.

The Controller should pass the IQueriable object to the view

```
IQueryable<comments> commentsList = commentsRepository.GetPostComments(1);
        return View(commentsList);
```

In the parent view (which renders the partial view) should use the @model directive as,

```
@model IQueryable<WebApplication1.Models.comments>
```

I modified @model directive in the partial view as,

```
@model IQueryable<WebApplication1.Models.comments>
```

Try once and it should work.